# how to submit email on netlify to ajax and html symbol replace to string

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to set not submit a blank email?

Anybody help us

```
let Form = document.querySelector("form");
Form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

async function handleSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    let myForm = document.getElementById('myAjax');
    let formData = new FormData(myForm);
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()
    }).then(() => console.log('Form successfully submitted')).catch((error) =>
        alert(error))
}
```